# É possivel colocar uma 'pré-imagem' no iframe do youtube?

Tags: html5, css3, youtube

Incorporei um vídeo do youtube nesse site: http://aresdapraca.com.br/

Gostaria de colocar uma imagem por cima do vídeo quando ele estiver pausado no inicio.

Já fiz isso mas era com  a tag 'video'. Da pra fazer isso com o iframe (isso pode ser chamado de API?) do youtube também?

Comment: Sim, você tem que usar a API do YouTube para fazer isso. Mas daí você pode colocar a capa manualmente. Mas o botão pra começar o vídeo e a capa sair de cima você usará a API. Vou tentar te postar um exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só adicionar o código no trecho indicado dessa url:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<codigo>/0.jpg
```

Exemplo

[image]

https://img.youtube.com/vi/uipTZ2re4Uk/0.jpg

O que eu fiz foi deixar uma imagem fixa. Quando o  usuário clica na imagem, o iframe (sem o src) recebe o atributo `src` , que está gravado num `data-src` da imagem.

Esses dias atrás, fiz algo parecido com isso:

```js
$(function(){
   $('#img').click(function ()
   {
     var src = $(this).data('src');
     
     $('#frame').attr({src: src});
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/zzOv14tnaWU/0.jpg" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzOv14tnaWU" />
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

Comment: O código no `iframe` não funcinou. Não sei se isso é alguma limitação do snippet

Comment: O meu código funcionou abaixo sem iframe também.

Comment: @DeeSouza, o meu mudou o `src` do `iframe`. Porém, não carrega o conteúdo

Comment: Sim. Dá esse erro: `Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzOv14tnaWU' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Comment: Por isso o meu exemplo é feito numa `div`, embora a API transforme no `iframe`.

Answer (score 2):

Veja:

```js
 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

 var player;

 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

 }

 function onPlayerReady(event) {
   event.target.playVideo();
 }

 function playVideo() {
   if (window.YT) {
     player = new YT.Player('player', {
       height: '360',
       width: '640',
       videoId: 'AcXC_T-TDeU',
       playerVars: {
         'autoplay': 0,
         'controls': 0,
         'rel': 0,
         'showinfo': 0
       },
       events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady
       }
     });
   }
 }
```

```css
 html {
   text-align: center;
 }
 #player {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 640px;
   height: 360px;
   background: url(http://placehold.it/640x360) no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
<p>
  <button onclick="playVideo()">Play</button>
</p>
```

No lugar da imagem de fundo `background`, você coloca sua capa. Se você quiser pode colocar o botão em cima capa com `position: absolute`. Daí vai do que tu precisa.